# Detect whether change was made by add-in

Tags: office-js

I am using [`onChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=office-js#onchanged) to detect when a change is made in a worksheet. In response to that change, my add in makes changes to other cells in the same worksheet. This causes the handler to be invoked infinitely after the first change made by a human. Is there a way to detect if the change was made by my add in as opposed to manually by a human? Or some other way to work around this issue?

Comment: On the face of it, it seems like you just need the logic of you handler to first check whether a cell's value needs to be changed and not change it if it is already changed. If that won't work, could you provide some more details of your scenario?

Comment: I think this would work, though it would complicate the logic a bit. Basically I'm using one cell in a row as a key and then filling in the rest of the row based on that value. I currently get and set the `values` of the whole row, but I see how I could get the ranges on either side of the key and leave that cell untouched.